# JQuery ui selectmenu placeholder is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I had added Jquery ui selectmenu placeholder is not working showing error

```
$.widget( 'app.selectmenu', $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _drawButton: function() {
        this._super();
        var selected = this.element
                .find( '[selected]' )
                .length,
            placeholder = this.options.placeholder;

        if (!selected && placeholder) {
            this.buttonText.text( placeholder );    
        }
    }
});

$('select').selectmenu({
    placeholder: 'Select a speed'
});
```

Error is `text is not defined`. I am using Jquery UI version 1.12.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
this.buttonText.text( placeholder );
```

try with:

```
this.buttonItem.text(placeholder);
```

buttonText does exist: you have only button and buttonItem and you need buttonItem to change the text.

Example:

```js
$.widget( 'app.selectmenu', $.ui.selectmenu, {
  _drawButton: function() {
    this._super();
    var selected = this.element
    .find( '[selected]' )
    .length,
        placeholder = this.options.placeholder;

    if (!selected && placeholder) {
      this.buttonItem.text(placeholder);
    }
  }
});
$(function () {
  $('#speed').selectmenu({ placeholder: 'Select a speed' });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="speed">Select a speed</label>
<select name="speed" id="speed">
    <option>Slower</option>
    <option>Slow</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>Fast</option>
    <option>Faster</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for `_drawButton`? I couldn't find any.

Comment: I do see it in the source code. Curious that it's not in the official documentation. Thanks for responding!