# jQuery selectmenu onchange

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I want to make a select menu with icons and the text you select should be shown in a text on top (or the icon). My problem is that the on change method is not working.

What's going wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var li = $("<li>"),
        wrapper = $("<div>", {
          text: item.label
        });

      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }

      $("<span>", {
        style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
        "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
      }).appendTo(wrapper);

      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("test")
    }
  });

  $("#icons_id")
    .iconselectmenu()
    .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");

});

var select = document.getElementById("icons_id");

var options = ["Aufgabe", "Gruppe", "Schritt", "Werkzeug", "Dokument"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

  var opt = options[i];

  var el = document.createElement("option");

  var icon = opt;

  el.style

  el.textContent = opt;

  el.value = opt;


  select.appendChild(el);

}

function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("icons_id").value;

  document.getElementById("demo_text").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;

}
```

```css
option.avatar {
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.avatar .ui-icon {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<h2 id="test">Dropdown Menu</h2>

<p id="demo_text">You selected: </p>

<select name="icons_name" id="icons_id" onchange="myFunction()">

  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">1</option>

  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">2</option>

  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">3</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Vandalising your own question is bad enough, but it's an affront that you attempt to vandalise answers by others by trying to remove the code therein.

Answer (score 2):

The `change` event of the original `<select>` element won't fire, since you're manipulating elements of the Selectmenu widget and not the `<select>`. You could manually trigger the `change` on the original element, e.g. `.trigger("change")`, but you might instead consider using the [Selectmenu widget's `change` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change) to fire your function.

In the snippet below, I've moved the `change` event out of the widget customization and into the `iconselectmenu` initialization.

Like this:

```
.iconselectmenu({
  change: myFunction
})
```

(Also see [Tom Maher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900276/924299) for a different way to define the `select` event handler.)

**Working example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var li = $("<li>"),
        wrapper = $("<div>", {
          text: item.label
        });

      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }

      $("<span>", {
        style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
        "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
      }).appendTo(wrapper);

      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
    }
  });

  $("#icons_id")
    .iconselectmenu({
      change: myFunction
    })
    .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");

});


var select = document.getElementById("icons_id");
var options = ["Aufgabe", "Gruppe", "Schritt", "Werkzeug", "Dokument"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  var icon = opt;
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("icons_id").value;
  document.getElementById("demo_text").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```css
option.avatar {
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.avatar .ui-icon {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<h2 id="test">Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p id="demo_text">You selected: </p>

<select name="icons_name" id="icons_id" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">1</option>
  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">2</option>
  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">3</option>
</select>
```

---

### Edit:

One way to add the icon to `#demo_text` is to reference the same `data-style` attribute you use when rendering the widget. Within the `change` event handler, I'm grabbing the background image and creating an icon element to append to `#demo_text` along with the selected option's value.

Also, since you're using jQuery, I chose to write the code in jQuery rather than vanilla JavaScript.

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {

      var li = $("<li>");

      var wrapper = $("<div>", {
        "text": item.label,
      });

      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }

      $("<span>", {
        "style": item.element.attr("data-style"),
        "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
      }).appendTo(wrapper);

      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);

    }
  });

  $("#icons_id")
    .iconselectmenu({
      change: myFunction
    })
    .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");

});


var options = ["Aufgabe", "Gruppe", "Schritt", "Werkzeug", "Dokument"];
var $select = $('#icons_id');
var $display = $('#demo_text');

$.each(options, function() {
  var $option = $('<option>', {
    "value": this,
    "text": this
  });
  $select.append($option);
});

function myFunction(e, ui) {
  var $value = $("<span>", {
    "text": $select.val()
  });
  var $icon = $("<span>", {
    "style": ui.item.element.data("style"),
    "class": "ui-icon "
  });
  $display.text('You selected: ').append($icon, $value);
}
```

```css
option.avatar {
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.avatar .ui-icon {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<h2 id="test">Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p id="demo_text">You selected: </p>

<select name="icons_name" id="icons_id" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">1</option>
  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">2</option>
  <option data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">3</option>
</select>
```

---

### Edit:

Here's an example of how to populate the `<select>` element purely from an array of objects, so that you can specify an icon for each `<option>`.

I also used code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271419/jquery-ui-selectmenu-placeholder-is-not-working) to show a "placeholder" for the dropdown prior to user selection.

I also switched from the `change` event to the `select` event. The first option is selected by default (even though the placeholder is showing), so `change` doesn't fire if you select it again.

```js
$(function() {

  /* Customize Widget */

  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _drawButton: function() {
      this._super();
      var selected = this.element
        .find('[selected]')
        .length,
        placeholder = this.options.placeholder;

      if (!selected && placeholder) {
        this.buttonItem.text(placeholder);
      }
    },
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {

      var style = "background-image:url('" + item.element.attr("data-icon") + "')";

      var li = $("<li>");

      var wrapper = $("<div>", {
        "text": item.label,
      });

      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }

      $("<span>", {
        "style": style,
        "class": "ui-icon"
      }).appendTo(wrapper);

      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);

    }
  });

  /* Define Select Handler */

  function chooseOption(e, ui) {
    var style = "background-image:url('" + options[ui.item.index]['data-icon'] + "')";
    var $value = $("<span>", {
      "text": $select.val()
    });
    var $icon = $("<span>", {
      "style": style,
      "class": "ui-icon"
    });
    $display.text('You selected:').append($icon, $value);
  }

  /* Define Select Options */

  var options = [{
      'value': 'Aufgabe',
      'text': 'Aufgabe',
      'data-icon': 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&r=g&s=16'
    },
    {
      'value': 'Gruppe',
      'text': 'Gruppe',
      'data-icon': 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&r=g&s=16'
    },
    {
      'value': 'Schritt',
      'text': 'Schritt',
      'data-icon': 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&r=g&s=16'
    },
    {
      'value': 'Werkzeug',
      'text': 'Werkzeug',
      'data-icon': 'https://picsum.photos/30/30/?image=2'
    },
    {
      'value': 'Dokument',
      'text': 'Dokument',
      'data-icon': 'https://picsum.photos/30/30/?image=12'
    }
  ];

  /* Generate Select Options */

  var $select = $('#icons_id');
  var $display = $('#demo_text');

  $.each(options, function() {
    var $option = $('<option>', this);
    $select.append($option);
  });

  /* Initialize SelectMenu */

  $("#icons_id")
    .iconselectmenu({
      placeholder: 'Select an Option',
      select: chooseOption
    })
    .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("ui-menu-icons");

});
```

```css
.ui-icon {
  background-position: left center;
}

#demo_text .ui-icon {
  margin: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p id="demo_text"></p>
<select name="icons_name" id="icons_id"></select>
```

Comment: thanks it works.. now the problem is, that the icon is not shown in the text

Comment: That's a separate issue. You'll need to add the icon element to `#demo_text`  in a similar way that you add it in the `_render` part of the widget.

Comment: how would you do this exactly? i have no idea

Comment: I've edited my answer to include one way to add the icon.

Comment: and do you also know how I do it that I still have a string array (or the same) that specifies the paths of the icons, which are then displayed in the option and the text?

Comment: because at the moment the generated options from the array just have an arrow as an icon

Comment: I edited again to demonstrate a way to specify each option's icon. However, this is out of the scope of your original question. You might consider posting a [different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) for other issues that come up. Just a friendly suggestion.

Comment: Ok thats works now thanks :D. Another thing: How is it with the size of the icon. At the moment only 16px icons works. Is it possible to use 32px icons?

Comment: Sure, but but you'll need to adjust the CSS to handle larger icons. The `.ui-icon` class in jQuery UI is set to 16px X 16px.

Comment: yea i got it :D And do u know how a could make an option in an option?

Comment: @showdev I've upvoted your answer as imho it's the more complete of all the answers given and I don't know why the op has not marked your answer as the correct solution.

Comment: yea i got it :D And do u know how a could make an option in an option?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you're having is that you are adding a select method to your widget not setting a select method on the base widget (selectmenu) to use as an event handler.

The following should work:

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _create: function(){
        this.element.on("selectmenuselect", function( event, ui ) {
            console.log("test");
        } ););
    }

    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var li = $("<li>"),
        wrapper = $("<div>", {
          text: item.label
        });

      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }

      $("<span>", {
        style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
        "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
      }).appendTo(wrapper);

      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You miss the value for options

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("icons_id").value;    
      document.getElementById("demo_text").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;    
    }
```

```html
    <h2 id="test">Dropdown Menu</h2>

    <p id="demo_text">You selected: </p>

    <select name="icons_name" id="icons_id" onchange="myFunction()">

      <option value="1" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">1</option>

      <option value="2" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">2</option>

      <option value="3" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">3</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was accepted, but it doesn't address the `selectmenu` widget at all. Also, if an `<option>` has no `value` attribute, its [text will be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34266512/924299).

Comment: Yes but it is the easiest way to solve that case. Thanks

Comment: To solve which case? The OP is [not having trouble](https://jsfiddle.net/4b37ts1v/) getting the `value`.

Comment: What do you think about the `value` and the `text` are different? What wrong when guide them the standard html?

Comment: I mean no offense. There's nothing wrong with your suggestion, but it might be better as a comment. The elements are valid without a `value` attribute, the OP's value and text don't differ, and including a `value` attribute doesn't solve the problem presented, in my opinion.